# Error Unexpected token "..." when compiling Vue JS with webpack and their modules

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I got a project with vuejs and when I run : node build/dev-server.js on my local machine i have this message.

This script works perfectly on the production machine with same package.json

npm -v : 6.14.7
node -v : V12.18.2

I don't know where is the problem, do you help me ?
I try to delete the "..." but I have some others errors.

```
ERROR in ./src/main.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: src/main.js: Unexpected token (38:2)

  36 |   router,
  37 |   store,
> 38 |   ...App
     |   ^
  39 | })
  40 |
```

(main.js) :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
import store from './store'
import App from './App'
import 'bulma/css/bulma.css'
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { faEye } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { faUsers } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { faTrophy } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
library.add(faEye)
library.add(faUsers)
library.add(faTrophy)
Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)

Vue.config.productionTip = false
import routes from './router/index.js'

import './util/mock.js'
Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.use(VueResource);
const router = new VueRouter(routes);
import jQuery from 'jquery'


window.jQuery = jQuery
window.$ = jQuery

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store,
  ...App
})
```

(dev-server.js) :

```
require('./check-versions')()
var config = require('../config')
if (!process.env.NODE_ENV) process.env.NODE_ENV = JSON.parse(config.dev.env.NODE_ENV)
var path = require('path')
var express = require('express')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var opn = require('opn')
var proxyMiddleware = require('http-proxy-middleware')
var webpackConfig = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'testing'
  ? require('./webpack.prod.conf')
  : require('./webpack.dev.conf')

// default port where dev server listens for incoming traffic
var port = process.env.PORT || config.dev.port
port = 9001;
// Define HTTP proxies to your custom API backend
// https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware
var proxyTable = config.dev.proxyTable

var app = express()
var compiler = webpack(webpackConfig)

var devMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
  publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
  stats: {
    colors: true,
    chunks: false
  }
})

var hotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler)
// force page reload when html-webpack-plugin template changes
compiler.plugin('compilation', function (compilation) {
  compilation.plugin('html-webpack-plugin-after-emit', function (data, cb) {
    hotMiddleware.publish({ action: 'reload' })
    cb()
  })
})

// proxy api requests
Object.keys(proxyTable).forEach(function (context) {
  var options = proxyTable[context]
  if (typeof options === 'string') {
    options = { target: options }
  }
  app.use(proxyMiddleware(context, options))
})

// handle fallback for HTML5 history API
app.use(require('connect-history-api-fallback')())

// serve webpack bundle output
app.use(devMiddleware)

// enable hot-reload and state-preserving
// compilation error display
app.use(hotMiddleware)

// serve pure static assets
var staticPath = path.posix.join(config.dev.assetsPublicPath, config.dev.assetsSubDirectory)
app.use(staticPath, express.static('./static'))

module.exports = app.listen(port, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
    return
  }
  var uri = 'http://localhost:' + port
  console.log('Listening at ' + uri + '\n')

  // when env is testing, don't need open it
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'testing') {
    opn(uri)
  }
})
```

Comment: Can you try adding, `components: { App }` instead of `...App`?

Comment: Thx for your reply, when I change ...App by App or components: { App }.
I have this error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module but the scripted compiles well.